# VB.NET 2008 DataGridView not Updating Visual Foxpro Database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm using VB.NET 2008 with a DataGridView and I'm interfacing to a Visual Foxpro 6 database using the vfpoledb.1 driver. When I change a value in the description field, it changes in the DataGridView but the database never gets updated. Do I need to use code to force the changes to take place?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim sConString As String = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=C:\MyDatabase.dbc;Mode=3;"
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConString)

    Private Function FetchData()

        con.Open()
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim sSQL As String
        sSQL = "SELECT item_cd, item_desc FROM invent;"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, con)
        Dim daInv As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim iRecCount As Integer
        iRecCount = daInv.Fill(ds, "invent")
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("invent").DefaultView
    End Function

    Private Sub btnFetchData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFetchData.Click
        Call FetchData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        con.Close()
        con = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the underyling problem and resolved it. The VFP table I'm accessing does not have a primary key defined. It does have indexes but they are simply marked as "Regular" indexes (using VFP terminology).

I was able to use a VFP tool call vRunFox (Visual Run Fox) from Ed Leafe's website to modify the table structure. I had to use some VFP commands to bring up the Table Designer window.

I also had to add some code to my FormClosing event. Here's what my FormClosing event looks like now:

```
    Dim myBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(daInv)
    myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    daInv.UpdateCommand = myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
    daInv.Update(ds.Tables("invent"))
    con.Close()
    con = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this code will update the Table and push the changes back to Database? I don't think so. I tried the same code with SQL Server 2005, and it is not working(I don't have a FoxPro db). So I modified the code and now it is working fine.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim sConString As String = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=C:\MyDatabase.dbc;Mode=3;"
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConString)
    Dim daInv As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Private Sub FetchData()
        con.Open()
        Dim sSQL As String
        sSQL = "SELECT item_cd, item_desc FROM invent;"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, con)
        daInv = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim builder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(daInv)
        Dim iRecCount As Integer
        iRecCount = daInv.Fill(ds, "invent")
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("invent").DefaultView
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFetchData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFetchData.Click
        Call FetchData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)
        daInv.Update(ds.Tables("invent"))
        con.Close()
        con = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Do you always have to run an explicit update command on a Data Adapter to push your updates? Is there someway I can push the update right away when a user is done editing a record?

Comment: I moved my variables ds, daInv and cmd to the top so that they are "globals" and then I put your code down where you suggested. When I try to run it I'm getting the following error message: Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Comment: I think you need to call it explicitly. I am not sure there an another way to do it. Let me try.

Comment: @HK1: I couldn't find any other links or code, which helps you to update the Database directly, but you can do something in the cellleave event and simulate such experience. But I don't think its good approach, because it will increase the network bandwidth.

Comment: OK, I got my OleDbCommandBuilder setup but it's bombing out because I don't have a primary key specified. I'm pretty sure the table does have one but the OLE DB connection/driver isn't recognizing it, apparently. Is there someway I can set a primary key on a DataSet table?

Comment: Its not required. I am not sure how foxpro works, but SQLServer I can update a Table without a PK. Is there any FK issues?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there aren't any Foreign Key issues. The error I'm getting is: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

Comment: @HK1: I have working an open source project SQLCEExplorer in which I am using the same terminology to Edit Tables. There I can update / insert / delete values from Tables without PK or FK

Comment: @Anuraj: I think this problem is unique to VFP and VB.NET/ADO.NET.

Comment: I found this: "As of the writing of this chapter, the Visual FoxPro OLE DB Provider does not work properly with the Command Builder. The Fox team was made aware of the problem, so there should hopefully be an updated version of the provider available by the time you read this." http://foxcentral.net/microsoft/NETforVFPDevelopers_Chapter07.htm

Comment: I suspect if I could specify a Primary Key in the DataSet Table somehow I could possibly write my own Update statement for my UpdateCommand and the problem would be resolved. The other conclusion I'm coming to very quickly here is that using ADO.NET with Visual Foxpro is not a good option. I'm probably going to resort to use VB6 or MS Access with the older plain-jane ADO.

Comment: @HK1: Check this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx

Comment: I think I found the underyling problem and resolved it. The VFP table I'm accessing does not have a primary key defined. It does have indexes but they are simply marked as "Regular" indexes (using VFP terminology). I was able to use a VFP tool call vRunFox (Visual Run Fox) from Ed Leafe's website to modify the table structure. I had to use some VFP commands to bring up the Table Designer window. I'll try out my code again when I get time.